# service installation on server 2003

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, service

I'm trying to install service which I created in visual studio 2008 on windows server 2003
the problem is that I'm keep getting the following error:

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

all the documentation I read about the issue suggested to install  .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1
my currently frame work is 3.5 so I guess it won't solve anything ,is there any solution to the issue ? if there is additional information I need to supply  please guide me since I'm new to the server,services world.

Comment: You should post your implementation of the overridden OnStart method in your class that inherits from ServiceBase.

Comment: You seem to assume there is some "issue" that can be "solved". This is more likely a bug in your service.

Comment: Did you check your event logs for any additional detail?

Comment: thanks all for replying  
 1. in the on start I call to method that start the all application :  
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)  
 { RunSearch(); }    

 2. I realy hope it is bug in my service cause i can handle it ,is there a way to find the source of the error? (the application is running fine in my test area)  
 3.I checked it after seeing your notes but there was nothing that i can use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service has any ongoing work to do, you should spawn a thread in `OnStart` and then return. If the service doesn't have ongoing work but may take a while to run, then you need to call `RequestAdditionalTime`.

The MSDN docs for managed Windows services are a bit lacking; [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/in-depth-how-net-managed-services-interact-with-the-servicecontrolmanager-scm-kim-hamilton) fills in the details nicely.

Comment: thanks !! I run the method in the on strat in a different thread and it worked like magic ;-)